# Miller: selecting columns based on their last value

Tags: miller

I'm processing a TSV file with a hundred columns and I would like to pick some of them based on their last values (ie. the value on the last row).

For instance with the following data (and I let you imagine 96 more columns!):

```
Year    An  Ti  Gi  Na
2000    5   10  2   3
2010    3   2   5   7
2020    6   3   5   6
```

I would like to select all columns whose value on the last row is at least 5 (and, better, I would like to select all columns whose value on the last row is at least the value of the row Gi).

So in the end, I would like the following output (the column Ti is discarded because its value on the last row is 3 which is below our threshold).

```
Year    An  Gi  Na
2000    5   2   3
2010    3   5   7
2020    6   5   6
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write this bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

gi_value=$(mlr --t2n tail -n 1 then cut -f Gi input.tsv)

gi_columns=$(mlr --t2n tail -n 1 then label 1 then reshape -r '^[a-zA-Z]' -o k,v then filter '$v >= '"$gi_value"'' then cut -f k then nest --ivar "," -f k input.tsv)

mlr --tsv cut -f Year,"$gi_columns" input.tsv
```

First extract the Gi value

```
mlr --t2n tail -n 1 then cut -f Gi input.tsv
```

to populate the `gi_value` var with `5` value.

Then extract the list of columns of the last row in wich the value is >= 5

```
mlr --t2n tail -n 1 \
then label 1 \
then reshape -r '^[a-zA-Z]' -o k,v \
then filter '$v >= '"$gi_value"'' \
then cut -f k \
then nest --ivar "," -f k input.tsv
```

This gives you in output `An,Gi,Na`.

The last step is to cut `An,Gi,Na` columns:

```
mlr --tsv cut -f Year,"$gi_columns" input.tsv
```

The output is

```
Year    An      Gi      Na
2000    5       2       3
2010    3       5       7
2020    6       5       6
```

Comment: Thanks!  I hoped that it could be solved with a single call to `mlr` but that's already very useful!

Comment: @mikael-s I think you can write some DSL script, and put it inside miller "put" verb.
This way it's easier for me

Comment: @mikael-s using a single `mlr` call would need to store the whole file in RAM until you reach the last row, which is where you can determine what to keep or discard; that's not optimal and can lead to a crash if the input file doesn't fit in RAM. @aborruso: here's a different way to get the list of fields that satisfy the condition: `mlr --itsv tail -n 1 then put -q 'print joinv(get_keys(select($*, func(k,v) {return v >= $Gi})), ",")'`

Comment: @Fravadona unfortunately I'm bad at using arrays. Every time I read you and think "wow!"